# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry<T>' to 'T'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I am using ASP.NET core 2.2 for developing web apis. I have the following method in repository class:

```
public async Task<Articles> AddAsync(Articles article)
{
   return await _context.Articles.AddAsync(article);
}
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry<Author.Command.Persistence.DBContextAggregate.Articles>' to 'Author.Command.Persistence.DBContextAggregate.Articles'
```

Here I am trying to use the AddAsync version to save the data.

Can anyone help me to provide their guidance to fix this issue?

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough code to identify the problem.  Show us the relevant code and the *entire stacktrace.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey As long as the `Articles` class is just a normal model it should be enough.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `AddAsync` method does not return just the provided type, in your case `Articles`. It does return `Task<EntityEntry>`. To fix your issue change your code to the following.

```cs
public async Task<Articles> AddAsync(Articles article)
{
   await _context.Articles.AddAsync(article);
   return article;
}
```

The changes made to the article instance will persist, since EFCore will track the provided Entity.
See the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addasync) for more information.

> What will basically happen now is that your `Articles` instance is added to the DBSet of the DBContext. If the primary key is generated for you, it will actually set it in the instance you provided the AddAsync method.

### EDIT

As `Chris Pratt` mentioned from the docs

> This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo', to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non async method should be used.

So you should instead use the synchronous versions `Add` instead.

So the code should look something like this.

```cs
public Articles Add(Articles article)
{
   _context.Articles.Add(article);
   return article;
}
```

Comment: How come the Task didn't show up in the stack trace?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am pretty sure it is due to the `await` keyword.

Comment: This is the error I received : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry<Author.Command.Persistence.DBContextAggregate.Articles>' to 'Author.Command.Persistence.DBContextAggregate.Articles'

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro: Yes, that's what you said in your original post.

Comment: FWIW, you're not supposed to actually use `AddAsync`. From the docs: "This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo', to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non async method should be used." Use `Add`, instead.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks for pointing that out, I updated my answer.

Comment: @ChrisPratt and Twenty thanks a lot for your response. It helped me to fix the issue :)